# SSL client authentication into Websphere MQ

Tags: java, ssl, websphere, ibm-mq, keystore

I'm trying to enable ssl client authentication in my java application for connecting to WMQ
I'm starting with this main class:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // Queue manager details
    String qmgrName = "MGR";

    String keyStorePath   = "keystore.jks";
    String trustStorePath = "keystore.jks";
    String password       = "changeit";

    // Create a keystore object for the keystore
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");

    // Open our file and read the keystore
    FileInputStream keyStoreInput = new FileInputStream(keyStorePath);
    try {
        keyStore.load(keyStoreInput, password.toCharArray());
    }
    finally {
        keyStoreInput.close();
    }

    // Create a keystore object for the truststore
    KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");

    // Open our file and read the truststore (no password)
    FileInputStream trustStoreInput = new FileInputStream(trustStorePath);
    try {
        trustStore.load(trustStoreInput, password.toCharArray());
    }
    finally {
        trustStoreInput.close();
    }

    // Create a default trust and key manager
    TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory =
            TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());

    KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory =
            KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());

    // Initialise the managers
    trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);
    keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, password.toCharArray());

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL"); // TLS
    System.out.println("SSLContextider: " + sslContext.getProvider().toString());

    sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);

    // Get an SSLSocketFactory to pass to WMQ
    SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

    // Set the socket factory in our WMQ parameters

    MQQueueConnectionFactory cf = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
    cf.setStringProperty(CommonConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, _IP);
    cf.setIntProperty(CommonConstants.WMQ_PORT, 1414);
    cf.setIntProperty(CommonConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, CommonConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
    cf.setStringProperty(CommonConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, "DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN");
    cf.setStringProperty(CommonConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, qmgrName);
    cf.setBooleanProperty(CommonConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, false);
    cf.setSSLCipherSuite("TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256");
    cf.setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);

        try (MQQueueConnection jmsConnection =
                     (MQQueueConnection)
                            cf.createQueueConnection();
             MQQueueSession session =
                     (MQQueueSession) jmsConnection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
             MQQueueSender sender =
                     (MQQueueSender) session.createSender(session.createQueue("DEV"))) {
            jmsConnection.start();

            sender.send(session.createTextMessage("aaa"));
        }
}
```

My problem is that when I will integrate my code in our application, I will have keystore file which contains multiples keys.
How can I specify which alias I want WMQ java client to use?

Comment: Can anyone help if there is a solution other than creating a new keystore file with single entry?